# Replace specific word in href with .data()

Tags: jquery, html

I can't find a way to replace "color1" from my href with .data('color') on button change. To be more specific I have this styleshhet:

```
<link id="custom-css" href="mysite/css/color1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

the switching buttons:

```
<label>
   <input type="radio" id="color2" name="colors" value="2" data-color="color2.css">
   <span class="color2"></span>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" id="color3" name="colors" value="3" data-color="color3.css">
    <span class="color3"></span>
</label>
```

So when the radio buttons are changing I want to replace only the "skin1" with .data('color') but so far replaces the entire href:

```
$('#my-group [type="radio"]').on("change", function() {
   $("#custom-css").attr("href",$(this).data('color'));      
   return false;
});
```

Comment: While it's possible to do this, it's not a great idea to be dynamically changing stylesheets at runtime. Instead use a single stylesheet and make the `change` event on the radio buttons add/remove a top-level class. Then in your CSS switch the relevant styles based on that parent class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. With your method i'll have to overwrite many elements as i'll have to target them with that parent class in front of it every time. Any idea how the above requested code will look? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding extra flag (data-current="color1.css"):

```
<link id="custom-css" href="mysite/css/color1.css" data-current="color1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

and the js will be:

```
$('#my-group [type="radio"]').on("change", function() {
   var newColor = $(this).data('color');
   var href = $("#custom-css").attr("href");
   var cur = $("#custom-css").data("current");
   href = href.replace(cur, newColor);
   $("#custom-css").attr("href", href);  
   $("#custom-css").data("current", newColor);      
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do I need to add data-current='' to the input buttons as well? Cause is not working.

Comment: Sorry I missed one variable. I fixed it now and it is working, please try.